# Is it alright to ask questions about how to phrase a puzzle?

Tags: discussion, policy, asking-questions

I have a math-flavored word puzzle that I like to give to my students, but I'm not happy with the way the puzzle is phrased. It has too many things that need to be explained to my students. Is it considered on-topic to ask "*What's a better way to phrase this puzzle*"?

The [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) tag suggests that, yeah, this is alright, but I just wanted to ask here to be sure.

Comment: Since this is fine, [I've gone ahead and posted my question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/60276/45155).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolutely. This is 100% within scope of the site. As you note, the [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) tag wiki even explicitly mentions phrasing (emphasis mine):

> This can cover all aspects of puzzle creation, from scrambling a rubiks-cube to **phrasing questions** to calculating all possible times a rope puzzle can produce.

*However*, a few things to note:

- You still need to ensure that your question is specific and answerable, rather than broad and discussion oriented or purely subjective (i.e. "How do I phrase X unambiguously?" is ok, but "What are some tips on phrasing puzzles?" is probably not).
- I've seen people who don't realise that questions about *making* puzzles (as opposed to questions that *are* puzzles) are in fact on topic, so unfortunately you may get a few stray downvotes or comments telling you it's off topic... Just ignore them. :)